# Como verificar se uma lista está dentro da outra?

Tags: python

Meu código:

```
n = [int(input()) for c in range(0, 5)]
lista = list(range(0, 10))
if n not in lista:
    print('1')
else:
    print('2')
```

Digito 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e a resposta é "1", sendo que os números de 1 à 5 estão dentro da "lista" que inclui os números de 0 à 10, então acho que não estou relacionando uma lista com a outra de forma correta. Gostaria de saber como verificar se os valores da primeira lista estão dentro da segunda, se caso o input for o exemplo que eu usei.

Comment: Não entendi. Você quer saber se a variável é uma lista ou se um determinado valor esta dentro da lista?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, agora a dúvida ficou mais clara?

Comment: Troque seu `if n not in lista:` para `if set(n).intersection(lista):`, veja se isso lhe ajuda.

Comment: Deu certo, pode me explicar como funciona essa estrutura e dar outros exemplos do tipo como usar para se "n"  não estiver em "lista"?

Comment: Já publico a resposta e explico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você usar o método `intersection` e verificar se há valores em comum no seu conjunto ou lista. Basicamente, ele checa se os elementos de `n` pertence a `lista`.

Veja:

```
n = [int(input()) for c in range(0, 5)]

lista = list(range(0, 10))

if set(n).intersection(lista):
  print('1')
else:
  print('2')
```

Você pode [consultar outros métodos](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) que pode lhe ajudar com operações em listas.

Veja mais sobre o [Intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)).

Comment: Se eu entrar com `1, 11, 12`, qual será a saída? Será o resultado correto? Por quê? E se eu entrar com `1, 1, 1`? A saída será 1 mesmo que a entrada não esteja contida em `lista`, visto que possui 2 uns a mais?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss qualquer elemento que esteja na faixa de `0..9` vai ser compatível com os elementos da `lista`, a não ser que você entre com valores acima de `9` que neste caso na vai estar nesta faixa.

Comment: Mas a lista 1, 11, 12 não dará uma interseção igual a 1 e entrar no if, mesmo que o 11 e o 12 não pertencem?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não sei se entendi muito bem desculpe. Se você entrar com os valores `1, 11, 12` vai dar erro porque você precisa entrar com 5 elementos, entretanto, se você entrar com `1, 11, 12, 13, 14` vai satisfazer a condição do `if` porque `1` intersecta com os valores na `lista`.